# Can the Giant Horse die?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Once tamed, can the Giant Horse die like any other horse? If it does: Will it respawn in its original area?

Or will it be lost forever?

> Unless revived by the horse fairy, but I assume that there is some maximum number of dead horses she will remember, meaning that the Giant Horse could eventually be lost from that list too.

Answer (score 4):

The Giant Horse is mortal, like any other horse. I don't know about it respawning (though I doubt it), but no dead horse is necessarily lost forever. The Horse Fairy southeast of the Highland Stable in the Faron region can revive lost horses for you.

Answer (score -1):

yes the giant horse can die, but if you wish to get it again untamed you can, or you could also use the horse fairy southeast of the highland stable to revive the horse tamed.